How to trigger sql statement from databricks notebook to sql warehouse
I am new to Databricks, I am trying to trigger a select statement from databricks notebook to serverless sql warehouse using the databricks sdk execute_statement and getting errors.
pip install databricks-sdk

from databricks.sdk import Workspace client

from databricks.sdk.service import sql

w = WorkspaceClient()

s = sql.StatementExecutionAPI(api_client=sql)

s.execute_statement(statement='show tables',warehouse_id='xxxx')

Error,
module databricks.sdk.service.sql' has not attribute 'do', upon checking the databricks sdk document, the 'do' is a part of API request,
    res = self._api.do('POST', '/api/2.0/sql/statements/', body=body, headers=headers)
    return StatementResponse.from_dict(res)

https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sdk-py/blob/main/databricks/sdk/service/sql.py
I am using sdk to avoid authentication part.
I am not sure what is the right way to provide parameters to trigger the query from a notebook to sql warehouse.
I have given api_client=sql as a guess and I can't see any documentation on this part.

are you using Azure databricks?
